# Shared properties with Spring Cloud Config

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-properties

We are thinking of migrating our Spring system to use Spring Cloud Config.

The system is made up of multiple services and some share properties for common resources such as the DB datasource. For these we have a 'base' config file which contains the commonly used properties in one place. Each of the services read the common file first and then overload their properties file on top. This saves us repeating common properties.

I can't see how we do the same with spring cloud config, I can see options for different repositories but not overloading property files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`application.yml` or `application.properties` is common to all applications.

Comment: Combined with [environment repository with a git back end][1]  I think (IMHO) one will have a lot of flexibility.

  [1]: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_environment_repository

Answer (score 0):

I have similar requirement to have a common/shared properties specific to set of services , but not for all services.

if we use application.properties, its global for all services. we need to have a shared json file specifically for a set of services only.

Any guidance on this requirement would be helpful.

Thanks guys..

Comment: I think will be more apropiate to post your question as a comment to the original question instead of answering to a question with a question :) As for your problem see my coment